# Take two lists and see if they can become each other with equation

Tags: list-manipulation, function-comparison

I have two lists `data1={1,2,3,4,5} data2={2,4,6,8,19}`I want a program to find if they are related and how for example the code would say times 2 or if they are not it would say that they are not related.

Sorry if this is completely off I am SUPER new to wolfram

Comment: do you mean you want to find if there is _the same ratio_ among each pair of numbers?? If you just want to find the ratio between each pair, just divide one data1 by data2?

Comment: As Nasser gets at, there are an infinite number of functions that map the first list to the second one.  For example, the data points `Transpose[{data1, data2}]` determine exactly one degree-4 polynomial (which has 5 parameters you could fit); but an infinite number of degree 5 polynomials fit.  So you have to frame the question a lot more carefully:  what kinds of relations are allowed?  (This is not a problem with Mathematica only; any programmatic approach would require the same sharpening of your question.)

Comment: Is it `CorrelationTest` instead that you are looking for?

Comment: I dont really care which function I just want one

Answer (score 1):

```
data1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
data2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

a = FindSequenceFunction[MapThread[List, {data1, data2}], n];
If[Head[a] === FindSequenceFunction, "Nope", a]
```

> 2 n

```
trythis = Table[{x, x^3 - 123}, {x, 6, 12}];
a = FindSequenceFunction[trythis, n];
If[Head[a] === FindSequenceFunction, "Nope", FullSimplify[a]]
```

> -123 + n^3